# How to reduce size of Tridion Jetty Log

Tags: tridion

Recently I ran a script to save many items in Tridion and noticed that the Jetty log for that day was around 500MB, compared to only 2MB from other days.

I assume the Solr Search Service, which uses Jetty, is logging when items are updated in the index.

Is it possible to change the log level or disable logging from Jetty while running batch scripts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the log level of jetty in the file C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\solr-jetty\conf\log4j.properties.